# Javascript function to return an array that needs to be in a specific order, depending on the order of a different array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, `reviews` which I get from an API endpoint. This object looks like this:

```javascript
[
  { name: "Facebook", count: 50 },
  { name: "Google", count: 43 },
  { name: "TripAdvisor", count: 67 },
  { name: "Other", count: 130 }
]
```

I have a [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) Pie chart that I'm feeding this data to. I'm using the `name` for the `labels` and the `count` for the size of each slice of the pie chart. Now, due to how chart.js works, I have to supply some hexadecimal colors to use as background colors, and the order in which the background color is being defined matters if I want the labels to match the colors properly. For example, if the order of the labels is `[A, B, C]`, an array of colors like `[red, green, blue]` means that A = red, B = green and C = blue. The problem is that the `reviews` array comes in a random order every single time from the API (I don't have control over the API and the data it gives me), so I can't just have a simple, predetermined array.

As far as I see, I have two options, I either sort the `reviews` array in some way, or I iterate over the data I get from the API and return an array based on some simple switch statements. I opted for the 2nd option, as it seems simpler for my usecase.

My current solution looks like this

```javascript
const chartBackgroundColor = collection => {
  let colorArray = [];
  const itemArray = collection.map(data => data.name);
  itemArray.forEach(item => {
      switch (item) {
        case "TripAdvisor":
          colorArray.push("#00B98B");
          break;
        case "Google":
          colorArray.push("#FFBD00");
          break;
        case "Facebook":
          colorArray.push("#4B6DAA");
          break;
        default:
          colorArray.push("#D9D9D9");
          break;
      }
    }
  )
  return colorArray;
}
```

The method works fine, but I was just curious whether there was some more elegant way of handling this issue, and whether a switch case is appropriate in this situation rather than a if/ifel/else tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would

- Encapsulate the names and colors in a data structure
- Use `.map` instead of `.forEach`

So something like this;

```
function chartBackgroundColor(collection){
  const nameColorMap = {
    "TripAdvisor": "#00B98B",
    "Google": "#FFBD00",
    "Facebook": "#4B6DAA",
  };
  return collection.map(data => nameColorMap[data.name] || "#D9D9D9");
}
```

Comment: Really nice one! Thanks for the help

Comment: Just as a small potential improvement, would it not be worthwhile declaring `nameColorMap` outside of the function? Means it could be used elsewhere (if exported) and won't be redeclared each time the function is run. I also believe the `=` sign should be removed on the return. Not sure if that's valid JS.

Comment: @DaneBrouwer if the map were to be used outside of this function -> Totally yes. Otherwise -> No. I imagine the speed gain would be minimal but the memory increase would be permanent.